# Css -webkit-backface-visibility shows white dots on rotated div

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV and it is rotated by:

```
transform: rotate(-5deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
```

It's good there, but when I add

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

It shos these white dots..

Any ideas? - thanks!

[image]

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/X5WKM/

Comment: It's a bad pixels on your screen :P

Comment: @NOX added demo http://jsfiddle.net/X5WKM/

Comment: If I turn backface visibility on (`-webkit-backface-visibility:visible`) for both `body` and `#top` they go away http://jsfiddle.net/X5WKM/1/. Also if I set `* {background:#f00}` dots become red indicating they're transparent not white. Not sure if that solves your problem (probably not, I assume you want backface-visiblity to be off) but hopefully it'll give someone an idea

Comment: I tested in Chrome 27 and there is no white dots.

Comment: @NOX I just tested this myself in Chrome 27 and there are white dots. They're a bit hard to see, but giving the `#foo` and `#top` a black background makes them very visible. http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/X5WKM/5

Comment: They seem to randomly appear on resizing. On certain sizes I have no ghost pixels at all. Looks like a bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're already well aware that the dots are caused by the `-webkit-backface-visibility` property. This appears to be a bug in Chrome v26- <strike>which, as NOX commented, appears to have been fixed in v27</strike> (just checked this myself, the issue is still present in v27 on Windows 7).

The simple *quick fix* for this involves replacing:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

With:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

#nav, #topp, #footer {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

This simply removes the `-webkit-backface-visibility` property from your `#top` and `#foo` elements - which doesn't appear to cause any harm.

Here is a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/X5WKM/3/) of this where I've made the background of the header and footer black to make it easier to see that the dots are no longer there at all.

---

As a side note, you should always put vendor prefixes before the real CSS properties. Instead of putting `-ms-transform` and `-webkit-transform` *after* `transform`, you should put them before:

```
-ms-transform: rotate(-5deg);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-5deg);
transform: rotate(-5deg);
```

Comment: I'm in Chrome 28 and I don't see any dots.